# Render example for dictionary of dictionaries with OpenAPI

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm in a situation where the whole openapi specification is splitted in multiple files that reference each other, like below. At the end of this chain, there is an example for DataContainer.yaml. However this doesn't get rendered. In fact, putting anything like a description causes a weird behaviour like the field being repeated both in the external and internal "dictionary". Where should I put this example to get it rendered?

```
#apis.yml

openapi: 3.0.1
...
paths:
  '/path/to/resource':
    $ref: './resources/myspec.yaml'
```

```
#myspec.yml

post:
  summary: Creates a new whatever
  parameters:
    - name: whatever
      in: path
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
  requestBody:
    required: true
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: '../schemas/CreateParams.yaml'
```

```
#CreateParams.yml

type: object
properties:
  name:
    type: string
    description: The default name
  data:
    $ref: './DataContainer.yaml'
```

```
#DataContainer.yml

type: object
additionalProperties:
  type: object
  additionalProperties:
    type: number
example:
  -1:
    0: 100000
    1: 200000
    2: 300000
    3: 400000
  0:
    0: 100000
    1: 200000
    2: 300000
    3: 400000
```

Comment: `externalValue` examples [are not displayed](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5433) by Swagger UI yet. Do you know how the example value was defined/referenced back when you used OpenAPI 2.0?

Comment: @Helen I was wrong and that most certainly didn't work even in OpenApi 2.0. I ended up adding the examples manually, but the same field is problematic. I updated the question.